# How to access subclass fields at runtime using superclass instance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two java objects: `WorkflowVo` and `TypeAWorkflowVo`. `TypeAWorkflowVo` is a subclass of `WorkflowVo`. WorkflowVo has fields - name, profitCenter. 
TypeAWorkflowVo has fields schedule, entity.

I store `TypeAWorkflowVo` in a list using

```
List<? extends WorkflowVo> lsWfItems  = new ArrayList<TypeAWorkflowVo>();
```

Is it possible to access the fields of `TypeAWorkflowVo`(schedule, entity) from `lsWfItems` at runtime?

I can only see `WorkflowVo` fields(name, profitcenter) at runtime. In other words, I only see `WorkflowVo` objects in `lsWfItems`. Please advise.

Comment: You need to cast `WorkflowVo` references to `TypeAWorkflowVo` first, there is a method called `cast` on the `Class` class, check the API docs for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have currently written it will not work. You do have a couple of options

1. Check that each item is of type TypeAWorkflowVo, then cast to this class and retrieve the values
2. Make the list with type argument of TypeAWorkflowVo
3. Make the fields on TypeAWorkflowVo available to be accessed through generic abstract methods on WorkflowVo
4. Move the fields to WorkflowVo

Each of these have their merits and fails and the decision will entirely depend on the situation and the definition of that object. Should the fields be on the super class or not? Should that list be of the sub class, or the super class. What do you gain out of each of these methods in the app. All these would be answered from the app

Answer (score 0):

> I store TypeAWorkflowVo in a list using

```
List<? extends WorkflowVo> lsWfItems  = new ArrayList<TypeAWorkflowVo>();
```

It is not possible.

`<? extends SomeThing>` doesn't allow to add anything in the Collection but `null`.

You should rather declare this if you want to be able to add `WorkflowVo` instances in the `List` :

```
List<WorkflowVo> lsWfItems = new ArrayList<WorkflowVo>();
```

> Is it possible to access the fields of TypeAWorkflowVo(schedule,
>   entity) from lsWfItems at runtime?

As you declare `List<? extends WorkflowVo> lsWfItems`, you should do a cast to `TypeAWorkflowVo` to use specify methods of it.
For example :

```
for (WorkflowVo workFlow : lsWfItems){
   if (workFlow instanceof TypeAWorkflowVo){
       TypeAWorkflowVo typeWorkFlow = (TypeAWorkflowVo) workFlow;
       ...
   }
}
```

Now, it you may avoid casting, it would be better.
Ideally, if you store only `TypeAWorkflowVo` instances in your `List`, declare rather :

```
List<TypeAWorkflowVo> lsWfItems = new ArrayList<TypeAWorkflowVo>();
```